# spark remove duplicate in each text file

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am looking at a standard or preferred way to do this:
I have a number of text files, each of the format:

file1:

```
word1 tag1 0.5
word1 tag2 0.4
word2 tag2 0.6
```

file2:

```
word1 tag3 0.7
word3 tag1 0.9
word2 tag2 0.3
```

As you see a word may have multiple "tag"s, in this case I need only to retain the one with the highest score **within each file**. so that

```
word1 tag2 0.4
```

is removed.

expected result:

```
word1 tag1 0.5
word1 tag3 0.7
word2 tag2 0.6
word3 tag1 0.9
word2 tag2 0.3 //keep this because it is from file2
```

I know I can read each file as individual RDDs and then sort and merge/join to produce my result, but is there a better way? e.g. feed all input files at once utilising

```
ctx.textFile(String.join(",", myfiles)); // myfiles = [file1, file2]
```

Thanks,

Comment: so you want to save for each tuple of word and file the tag with the highest score?

Comment: Yes but only within each file, you can see from my example, "word2 tag2" is kept twice because they are from two files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things: Add the filename to the data and find the relevant maximum afterwards.

```
val df = spark.read.options(Map("sep"->" ")).csv("/file*").withColumn("filename",input_file_name())
```

This results in:

```
scala> df.show()
+-----+----+---+--------------------+
|  _c0| _c1|_c2|            filename|
+-----+----+---+--------------------+
|word1|tag1|0.5|hdfs://hmaster:90...|
|word1|tag2|0.4|hdfs://hmaster:90...|
|word2|tag2|0.6|hdfs://hmaster:90...|
|word1|tag3|0.7|hdfs://hmaster:90...|
|word3|tag1|0.9|hdfs://hmaster:90...|
|word2|tag2|0.3|hdfs://hmaster:90...|
+-----+----+---+--------------------+
```

now we want to keep only the relevant ones, we can do this using argmax (see https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1023043053387187/3170497669323442/2840265927289860/latest.html):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val targetDF = df.groupBy($"_c0", $"filename").agg(max(struct('_c2, '_c1)) as "tmp").select($"_c0", $"tmp.*")
```

Result:

```
scala> targetDF.show()
+-----+---+----+
|  _c0|_c2| _c1|
+-----+---+----+
|word2|0.3|tag2|
|word1|0.7|tag3|
|word2|0.6|tag2|
|word1|0.5|tag1|
|word3|0.9|tag1|
+-----+---+----+
```

You should probably rename the columns of course